# Understand SciKit Learn CV Validation Scores

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand the output of cv_validation_scores, when running a GridSearchCV. The documentation does not adequately explain this.

When I print `grid_search.grid_scores_`, I get a list with items, like this:

```
[mean: 0.60000, std: 0.18002, params: {'tfidf__binary': True, tfidf__ngram_range': (1, 1)....
```

which makes sense. However, when I try to unpack each instance of grid_scores, I get:

```
[0] same dictionary as above, makes sense
[1] score for all folds, makes sense
[2] a list that I don't understand, that looks like, "[ 0.75        0.33333333  0.66666667]"
```

What are the scores being reported here?

Comment: Could you maybe also post the actual instance of grid_scores you are talking about? Also, is [1] a list or just a score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I posted on the mailing list, [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV) makes this quite clear:

> grid_scores_ : list of named tuples
>
> Contains scores for all parameter combinations in param_grid. Each entry corresponds to one parameter setting. Each named tuple has the attributes:
>
> ```
>         parameters, a dict of parameter settings
>         mean_validation_score, the mean score over the cross-validation folds
>         cv_validation_scores, the list of scores for each fold
> ```

These are the scores per fold in the cross-validation.

Comment: Ohh, so the overall score for all 3 folds is in [1], but for each of the 3 is divided out in [2]?

Comment: For some reason it didn't make sense when I read the documentation. I'm not sure why

Comment: Yes, indead, [1] is the mean of [3].

Comment: Andreas, you made a comment about the mailing list. I'm not getting any of that mail.

Comment: Did you subscribe to the mailing list? Otherwise your will not get a reply.

Answer (score 0):

I unsubscribed and resubscribed. Seems to work now